# Understanding the physics of a vertical axis wind turbine

Tags: aerodynamics

I have a physics background, but not much aerospace. I'm attempting to understand the operating principal of a vertical axis wind turbine. I've found a paper with a free body diagram, which I mostly understand, but I'm stuck on one concept.

Paper: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/274340439_Modal_analysis_of_a_small_vertical_axis_wind_turbine_Type_DARRIEUS

Figure in question:

[image]

My misunderstanding is related to the direction of the green arrow "lift forces" on the top and bottom airfoils. Assuming the direction of the lift force vector of the top airfoil is correct (down/left) I would expect the direction of the lift force vector of the bottom airfoil to point up/left. Clearly I'm wrong, cause the turbine would not function if this were true. But I'm curious if someone can help me understand why I'm wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: The picture of the bottom airfoil and all of the vectors associated with it is just a 180 degree rotation of the picture of the top airfoil and all of its vectors. Otherwise they are identical. In particular, the "lift" generated by the top airfoil makes the same angle with its relative wind as the "lift" generated by the bottom airfoil makes with _its_ relative wind. Why would you expect them to behave differently?

Comment: The airfoil is rotated by 180 deg, the lift vector is not.

Comment: This might help - [Vertical Axis Wind Turbine Aerodynamics and Design](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ldt405jIR0E)

Comment: D'Oh! Stupid of me! Of course, because the wind doesn't rotate. But look at the angles between the relative wind vector (black) and the lift vector (green) and the chord of the airfoil in both places, and I think you will see the similarity between the top and bottom cases.